# Possible to represent fixed-length arrays / "tuples" with @mojotech/json-type-validation?

Tags: typescript

Using [@mojotech/json-type-validation](https://github.com/mojotech/json-type-validation), what would a decoder for type `[number, number, number]` look like?

For example,

```
import { array, Decoder, number } from '@mojotech/json-type-validation'

type customTuple = [number, number, number]

const tupleDecoder: Decoder<customTuple> = array(number())
```

results in:

```
Error:(5, 7) TS2322: Type 'Decoder<number[]>' is not assignable to type 'Decoder<[number, number, number]>'.
  Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type '[number, number, number]'.
    Property '0' is missing in type 'number[]'.
```

Comment: @Li357 that didn't go so well, after adding the missing properties like `map` and `splice` it was complaining about, it warned about a missing index signature :(

Comment: Oh yeah, that was a bad idea. It seems like rorscach has your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From quickly going through the documentation it seems like there's no real way to achieve this with your `customTuple`. You're going to have to declare a `Decoder` with a normal `number[]` type.